# Random freezes, Radeon mentioned in the console

Tags: 11.10, freeze

I try to run Ubuntu 11.10. I tried :

- 64 bits release
- 32 bits release
- live CD

Ubuntu is freezing randomly... I don't know why. Mouse is freezing, screen go black then appear again, mouse is moving but I can't do anything.

Note : freeze can append if I run Firefox during install.

11.04 was perfect. I've never had such troubles...

I'm not a power user, just a fan... So I can't bring you informations.
I just have:

- a classic SATA

  - disk 1 primary partition with Windows,
  - 1 logical with Ubuntu,
  - 1 primary with personal data.
- USB mouse.
- Ethernet cable.
- ATI RadeonHD card

When I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> command, I have a lot of messages with errors. Radeon is repeated a lot of times.

Comment: When I use CTRL ALT F1 command, I have a lot of messages with error. Radeon is repeted a lot of times

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 4):

I also faced a single instance after the upgrade where the freeze happened, but could not reproduce it. You may like to read this link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/Freeze. You can file a bug by providing more information about it to the developers.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a permanent solution...simply press super key(windows key),it will open the unity dash & just move the cursor(using mouse/track-pad)...then press Esc/Super key

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem on diferent machines. I fixed it with new driver from `ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates` I think everyone of you have a nvidia graphic card too.
I saw that xorg process runs on 99 % cpu usage and blocked everything.

So that is my solution.